# docker-compose build after every code change

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i've been working with docker for two month and I always did the same steps.
I have a `docker-compose.yml` where the differents services are.
One of them is coded by me in a `Dockerfile`

When I change my code I always do `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`.
What the docker compose does it to start a python server.

Is it correct the way i'm working? I should instead use volumes while i'm coding?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds good to me.  Can you share the compose file?  You'll only need a volume if you want to mount code / data from your host machine.  You should stear away from copying code / data into the image via your Dockerfile.